# SQL UK Telephone Format Check

Tags: validation, phone-number

I'm trying to create some sort of validation checker within SQL that will validate a UK telephone number, I've looked at some examples and can see that these are all US numbers which can contain hyphens and drop the leading zero however in the UK we keep the leading zero and don't hyphenate the number.

For example:

01234568790

0123 456 8790

0123 4568790

4568790

456 8790

These are all UK possibilities. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try using *regular expression* (this feature is DBMS depended)

Comment: Note that the UK telephone system no longer supports dialling without STD code (this used to work until fairly recently for local numbers, but not any more). So your last two examples are no longer valid, which probably makes the validation easier.

Comment: no specific example code attempt given and no description of what sort of SQL is used.  Question is incomplete so voting to close

Comment: Have you asked the front end developers for this. There is a lot more leniency when dealing with country codes and other mobile/phone factors in the front end. Have them sort it out. If are looking for extra checks in the db then how will you take into account country code and what not.